# How can you get console backgrounds for Arch Linux?

Tags: boot, freebsd, opensuse, tty, init

I have tested out openSUSE and found that the tty1 is a bit different from other systems as the tty has got a background. I know that Knoppix has a tux penguin for each core the computer has, but I'm not quite sure how I can set the background image for the tty terminal..

**I want to have a tty terminal with a background image.** How exactly can this be done?

An example would be the OpenSUSE Gnome-shell LiveCD. When you boot up openSUSE, you see a splash screen (on tty1) so you press [Esc] the splash screen goes away, but you keep the background and the text explaining where we are up to while booting.

I am specifically interested in doing this on Arch. Will this require re-compiling the Linux kernel?

Other questions:

- What can we do to the was the tty terminal is displayed?
- Can each tty have it's own background image? If yes, how?

  - I'm guessing having multiple entries in a config file?
- Can the font color be changed?

  - [solved] -- vidcontrol for FBSD..

Google for some reason is not being friendly with the results, no matter what I try all links that are actually related have no answers.

**Edit:** I've figured out that the frame-buffer is is being. How do i use it?

Mplayer can use the frame-buffer to watch video on a tty terminal:

```
mplayer -vo fbdev google_main.mp4
# http://youtube.com/demo/google_main.mp4
```

So how can I make a underlay? (opposite to overlay in which mplayer has done)

**Note:** From when I posted this question, I have switched to Archlinux.. ( Debian no more )

**Note:** Today I don't really care about these decorations. Although would still be somewhat interesting to have. I have found what I would need but I've forgotten what the package/program was. If anyone still wants to answer with the package's name would still be good for anyone else who may want to do the same.

**Edit:** I've found what is required to set the background/console decorations. https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Kernel_Mode_Setting

Comment: @James ... the cantebury stuff feels like it isn't realy a part of the question. You should probably remove it

Comment: @xenoterracide: I'm done editing, is it better now?

Comment: @james I don't understand why we need the why in this case.

Comment: @james also systemd should be its own question, please one question per question

Comment: @xenoterracide: Okay, thanks for the tip about that systemd part, and the why is mainly just there to show an example of usage on what I intend to do. Is that not a good enough reason?

Comment: @James I get tired of trying to help people help themselves, I could (probably should) just edit your question... but I'll let the answer's your getting speak for themselve's. Your question is too long, contains more than 1 question, contains a bunch of rambling. Just ask what you need to know and that's it, no one cares about the rest. The only time anyone asks *why* is when what you're doing seems like a really bad idea.

Comment: @xenoterracide: Okay, thanks for the tips, I'll edit away "the rest" for you. ;)

Comment: @James this question was impossibly convoluted. I see @xenoterracide helped you some, but you need to keep going with the direction he gave. I couldn't judge if the recent answer was even relevant to the question because I couldn't figure out what you were asking on a first read. I just re-wrote it for you so that at least the main question is clear, but there were at at least 5 extra questions buried in there. Please consider removing these entirely until you answer your main question, then if you need to ask more specific questions later on.

Comment: The kernel implemented tty itself can't support background image, but running a non-X userspace terminal emulator is possible, solutions like fbterm is an example of this, it doesn't use tty, but pty and framebuffer API for rendering.

Comment: Also some sentences of this question is not written in proper English

Answer (score 2):

**To get rid off the boot image:**
On other distros the idea is the same -> splash=no in boot kernel commandline or change the picture in /etc/bootsplash or equivalent.

On open suse 11.4 (and probably some earlier versions of suse) you can get rid of that background picture by using Yast on command line as follows:

System -> Boot Loader -> From boot images choose the one already marked -> Edit ->
Optional kernel Command line parameters: change -> splash=no
after that you have a professional black background as it should be.

**To change this tty background picture to something nice:**

Find this directory -> /etc/bootsplash/themes/opensuse/images and replace the file with your screen size to something you like. Don't change the file name! Just put something else there with that same name. In same size, of course :)

Comment: [+1 -- It helps with understanding what openSuse has done] Well that does say how to disable or change it on opensuse, but does not say how to use these console decorations on another distro like debian.. ( From when I posted this question, I've switched to archlinux, and now in the progress of switching to freebsd.. Also I still have no console backgrounds, X is my current workaround )

Comment: humm, decided to not switch to freebsd. for many other reasons. so sticking with archlinux.