# How to know what to grep for in dmesg?

Tags: linux, logs, dmesg

I recently had some trouble with a wireless card, and an online forum suggested searching `dmesg` with `grep firmware`. That helped, I was able to find the problem immediately! However, the previous hour was spent looking at `dmesg` and I couldn't identify anything relevant due to the overwhelming quantity of information!

**How does on know what to grep for in dmesg?**

Sure, this was a hardware issue but I myself would never have thought to grep for the string "firmware". For someone *not* intimately familiar with the output of `dmesg`, how might I make some educated guesses about what to grep for?

Comment: I'm afraid that this question is not answerable as is. There're thousands of various stuff you can look for.

Comment: Thousands, yes, but surely there may be some guidelines. There are thousands of words in English, but there are guidelines on how to google a problem!

Comment: @dotancohen Can you please elaborate on the issue with the card? Also, you can try `lspci -vnn | grep -i net` taken from this [answer in super user](http://superuser.com/questions/760449/how-can-i-find-the-usb-wireless-adapter-into-the-dmesg-log-file)

Comment: It seems that what you are looking for is some sort of documentation on the output of dmesg. Is this correct?

Comment: @richard: That is what I was googling for, when I decided that I had better ask this question! I'm looking for ideas about how to build the intuition about what to grep for.

Comment: @Simply_Me: I've already resolved the issue with the wireless card, but I realized that I don't have the intuition to know what to grep for. Thus, here we are as I ask for guidelines.

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/110100/44370) maybe. The question of which lexicon is used with messages in the logs is related. You can explore it!

Comment: WARNING: dmesg reads from the kernel ring buffer, which means that if there are lot of messages the older ones get overwritten.  Generally items that would be retrieval via dmesg get written via syslog (if appropriately configured) to the system log file (usually /var/log/messages).

Comment: @illuminÉ: Great link, thank you! I will definitely get some ideas from the script.

Comment: @dotancohen thankyou for clarifying.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Something like this would be useful:

```
dmesg | grep -iC 3 "what you are looking for"
```

For example, if looking for your video card, you could try:

```
dmesg | grep -iC 3 "video"
```

Or:

```
dmesg | grep -iC 3 "graphics"
```

The `C 3` flag will print 3 lines before and after the matched string, just to give you some context on what the results are.  But as [@tohecz](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/22723/tohecz) said, there are thousands of possibilities.

All depends on what you are looking for... *sound, wifi, usb, serial, reader...*.

If you expect a usb key to appear in there, you can try grepping for `/dev/sd`.

---

Just found [this page](http://www.linfo.org/dmesg.html), that contains sound advice on how to grep stuff in there:

> Because of the length of the output of `dmesg`, it can be convenient to
>   pipe its output to grep, a filter which searches for any lines that
>   contain the string (i.e., sequence of characters) following it. The `-i`
>   option can be used to tell grep to ignore the case (i.e., lower case
>   or upper case) of the letters in the string. For example, the
>   following command lists all references to `USB` (universal serial bus)
>   devices in the kernel messages:
>
> ```
> dmesg | grep -i usb
> ```
>
> And the following tells dmesg to show all serial ports (which are
>   represented by the string tty):
>
> ```
> dmesg | grep -i tty
> ```
>
> The dmesg and grep combination can also be used to show how much
>   physical memory (i.e., RAM) is available on the system:
>
> ```
> dmesg | grep -i memory
> ```
>
> The following command checks to confirm that the HDD(s) is running in
>   DMA (direct memory access) mode:
>
> ```
> dmesg | grep -i dma
> ```

Comment: Nice idea. In fact I am familiar with the `C` flag.