# Heirloom Toolchest tr: error(s) trying to delete the complement of a set containing a multibyte character?

Tags: unicode, tr

I'm trying to use the [`tr`](http://heirloom.sourceforge.net/man/tr.1.html) command from the [Heirloom Toolchest](http://heirloom.sourceforge.net/tools.html) to overcome a [current limitation](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/106341/44370) of the *coreutils* implementation, so as to be able to "pump" (with the `-dc` options) multibyte characters from a "random" generator (*/dev/urandom*) to the terminal. Noteworthy is the fact that this has been [compiled](http://heirloom.cvs.sourceforge.net/heirloom/heirloom/README?view=markup) from source on *Archbang* after having failed to do so using the AUR [version(s)](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/?O=0&K=heirloom).

To simplify this, let's pick a character(☠) and figure out its octal value because this is how it must be expressed for toolchest `tr`:

```
echo '☠' | hexdump -b            # -b for octal
0000000 342 230 240 012                                                
0000004
echo -e '\0342\0230\0240'        # uses the "0nnn" format, make sure it prints
☠
```

There is a difference in how the octal value is expressed in *Bash* with the `echo` [builtin](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Bash-Builtins) (*0nnn*) compared to the toolchest `tr` here (*nnn*):

> The character '\' followed by 1, 2 or 3 octal digits stands for the
>   character whose byte code is given by those digits. Multibyte
>   characters can be specified as a sequence of octal bytes.

Let's try it. The `-dc` option simply deletes the complement of SET1. You specify a single set, and anything from standard input that doesn't contain an element from the set gets discarded:

```
echo '012345' | /usr/5bin/tr -dc '456'   #sanity check
45                                       #all good
```

Now these:

```
echo -e '\0342\0230\0240' | /usr/5bin/tr -dc '\342\230\240'
echo -e '☠' | /usr/5bin/tr -dc '☠'
```

which should both print one(1)☠, or ultimately the following (much more characters) all produce the same error:

```
/usr/5bin/tr -dc '\342\230\240' < /dev/urandom

*** Error in `/usr/5bin/tr': double free or corruption (!prev): 0x0000000000d24420 ***
```

Actually every time the input and SET1 both contain the chosen character the error appears with `-dc`. The behavior is also the same accross the *SysV 3rd, 4th, Posix, Posix2001, or ucb(BSD)* versions of the command provided in the toolchest. Sometimes, as with the case of `tr -dc '1' < /dev/urandom` I get a segfault proper or some few lines of output followed with this:

```
Error in `/usr/5bin/tr': realloc(): invalid pointer: 0x00007f93ee284010 ***
======= Backtrace: =========
/usr/lib/libc.so.6(+0x73f8e)[0x7f93ee338f8e]
/usr/lib/libc.so.6(+0x7988e)[0x7f93ee33e88e]
/usr/lib/libc.so.6(realloc+0x1c8)[0x7f93ee342918]
/usr/5bin/tr[0x401a74]
/usr/5bin/tr[0x400e93]
/usr/lib/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf0)[0x7f93ee2e5000]
/usr/5bin/tr[0x400f63]
======= Memory map: ========
00400000-00403000 r-xp 00000000 08:21 1579535                            /usr/5bin/tr
00602000-00603000 rw-p 00002000 08:21 1579535                            /usr/5bin/tr
0067a000-006bc000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                                  [heap]
7f93edc6e000-7f93edc84000 r-xp 00000000 08:21 1448153                    /usr/lib/libgcc_s.so.1
7f93edc84000-7f93ede83000 ---p 00016000 08:21 1448153                    /usr/lib/libgcc_s.so.1
7f93ede83000-7f93ede84000 rw-p 00015000 08:21 1448153                    /usr/lib/libgcc_s.so.1
7f93ede84000-7f93ee2c5000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f93ee2c5000-7f93ee469000 r-xp 00000000 08:21 1440453                    /usr/lib/libc-2.19.so
7f93ee469000-7f93ee669000 ---p 001a4000 08:21 1440453                    /usr/lib/libc-2.19.so
7f93ee669000-7f93ee66d000 r--p 001a4000 08:21 1440453                    /usr/lib/libc-2.19.so
7f93ee66d000-7f93ee66f000 rw-p 001a8000 08:21 1440453                    /usr/lib/libc-2.19.so
7f93ee66f000-7f93ee673000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f93ee673000-7f93ee694000 r-xp 00000000 08:21 1440340                    /usr/lib/ld-2.19.so
7f93ee6eb000-7f93ee874000 r--p 00000000 08:21 1448356                    /usr/lib/locale/locale-archive
7f93ee874000-7f93ee877000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f93ee891000-7f93ee893000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f93ee893000-7f93ee894000 r--p 00020000 08:21 1440340                    /usr/lib/ld-2.19.so
7f93ee894000-7f93ee895000 rw-p 00021000 08:21 1440340                    /usr/lib/ld-2.19.so
7f93ee895000-7f93ee896000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fffed79c000-7fffed7bd000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack]
7fffed7e9000-7fffed7eb000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                          [vdso]
ffffffffff600000-ffffffffff601000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                  [vsyscall]
```

Is all that suggesting a compiling error on my part or am I not using this properly?

---

With the contributed **patch** we have:

```
echo -e '\0342\0230\0240' | /home/me/bin/trsc -dc '\342\230\240'
echo -e '☠' | /home/me/bin/trsc -dc '☠'
☠
```

As we should!! But:

```
/home/me/bin/trsc -dc '\342\230\240' < /dev/urandom
```

still remains a mystery as the picked character is not in the output...

Comment: Good question and certainly it will help future internauts when doing a web search. Shame questions too often aren't considered worth the reward of upvoting. +1 from me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've seen that before. A bug. Try:

```
--- tr.c        6 Sep 2005 23:04:11 -0000       1.10
+++ tr.c        30 May 2014 09:46:33 -0000
@@ -291,7 +291,6 @@
                if(c<ccnt) code[c] = d;
                if(d<ccnt && sflag) squeez[d] = 1;
        }
-       free(vect);
        while((d = next(&string2)) != NIL) {
                if(sflag) squeez[d] = 1;
                if(string2.max==NIL && (string2.p==NULL || *string2.p==0))
```

(that was from a quick look a few months ago, while this patch will get you going, I can't guarantee it's right. Apply with `patch -l`).

Now also note that `/dev/urandom` provides with a stream of *bytes*. In UTF-8, not all sequences of bytes map to valid characters. For instance, 0x41 0x81 0x41 is not valid because `0x81` is `>=` 0x80, so it can only occur in a sequence of 2 or more over 0x80 bytes.

An invalid byte, because it's not in the set of characters that is the complement of ☠, will not be deleted by `tr`.

Better would probably be:

```
recode ucs-2..u8 < /dev/urandom | tr -cd ☠
```

ucs-2 being the characters U+0000 to U+FFFF encoded on 2 bytes per character, `/dev/urandom` looks more like a stream of ucs-2 characters. (we're missing the characters U+10000 to U+10FFFF though).

But that would still include the [D800..DFFF surrogate pair range](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16#Code_points_U.2BD800_to_U.2BDFFF)
which `mbrtowc(3)` will choke on (at least with my version of libc).

Those code point are reserved for the purpose of UTF-16 encoding. d800dc00 for instance is the UTF-16BE encoding of U+10000, but there's no U+D800 character or U+DC00. The UTF-8 encoding of those don't make sense as a character either (even if adjacent).

So you'd need to exclude them first:

```
perl -ne 'BEGIN{$/=\2;binmode STDOUT,":utf8"}
          $c = unpack("n",$_); if ($c < 0xd800 || $c > 0xdfff) {
            no warnings "utf8"; print chr($c)
          }' < /dev/urandom | tr -cd ☠
```

If the point is to get a stream of random Unicode characters encoded in UTF-8, best would probably to get a random code point in the allowable range (0..0xd7ff, 0xf000..0x10ffff) and convert that to UTF-8. If you want to base it on `/dev/urandom`, you could use 3 bytes (24 bits) from it for each code point:

```
perl -ne 'BEGIN{$/=\3;binmode STDOUT,":utf8"}
          $c = unpack("N","\0$_") * 0x10F800 >> 24;
          $c+=0x800 if $c >= 0xd800;
          do {no warnings "utf8"; print chr($c)}' < /dev/urandom |
  tr -cd ☠
```

Comment: Works great! Of course because of the odds, it takes 10-15 secs for 3 lines of that single char to show. Increasing the set to 20 chars (15multi/5ascii), I get 3 lines per second or so, which is quite satisfying in context! The allowable range version is considerably slower because of the odds I guess. Also what I always find surprising is that the chars don't come one at a time - obviously something fills up then outputs. Thank you again. Cheers!